# How to prove that the square root of "$9n+3$" is not natural?

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

How should I prove that the square root of $9n+3$ is not natural?

Comment: Just to clarify: by "not natural"... do you mean, not in the set of natural numbers?  If so, then try supposing that the square root of 9n+3 is a natural number, square it, then try to find a contradiction.

Comment: What do you know about squares of integers? Can you think of a condition which is satisfied by every square but not by $9n+3$?

Comment: More specifically, consider the square of a multiple of 3 and the square of a number which is not a multiple of 3.

Comment: I reached 9|k^2-3. what should i do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice we have $$9n+3=3(3n+1)$$
For any natural number $n$, $(3n+1)$ is not the multiple of $3$

For $3(3n+1)$ to  be a perfect square natural number, it should have $(3n+1)$ as the multiple of $3$ which is not. Thus, $3(3n+1)$ is never a square natural number.

Hence, square root of $(9n+3)$ is not a natural number

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 
$$ 9n+3=m^2 \tag{1}$$
we have that $3$ divides the LHS, hence $3$ divides the RHS, hence $3\mid m$, hence $9$ divides the LHS, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Modulo 9,
the square of
$0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
\bmod 9
= 0, 1, 4, 0, 7, 7, 0, 4, 1
$
and none of these are $3$.

If $9n+3$ was a square of an integer,
it would be congruent to
one of those;
obviously, it is not.

Note that
none of
$9n+2, 3, 5, 6, 8$
can be squares.

This is the start
of the path to quadratic residues.